# Is it possible to crawl list for every 5 minutes in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: search, content-search-web-part

Is it possible to crawl custom list data for every 5 minutes in SharePoint 2013 to retrieve latest results. I want to use content search webpart to display results from list, I need results within 5 minutes.

Comment: You can schedule your incremental crawl to run at every 5 minutes interval. However you need to limit your content source size. If there are too many items to be crawled it may not have enough time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Continuous Crawling rather than incremental crawls. You will have to make that determination based on the scale and performance of you farm. Out of the box continuous crawling runs about every 15 minutes. It is possible to decrease this setting, though not often advisable.

Another option is to use CSOM/REST rather than search. This references the content directly and does not require a crawl at all.